# Java Getting the Exact Value from N raised to n

Tags: java, bigdecimal

i have this simple problem.

Sample input:

input one
`95.123`

input two `12`

Raising the first input to second input must give the exact value of the power.
like this : `548815620517731830194541.8990253434157159735359672218698`

I can't get it right.

here is what i have done so far. I think i'm missing something

```
System.out.println("Input One");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
Double inputOne = scanner.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Input Two");
Double inputTwo = scanner.nextDouble();
Double result = Math.pow(inputOne, inputTwo);
BigDecimal big = new BigDecimal(result);
System.out.println(big);
```

what am i missing out?

Comment: I believe that result is too big to fit in a `double` (which is what `Math.pow` is returning).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> what am i missing out?

You're using `double` to start with, and `double` can't represent 95.123 exactly. You're then using `Math.pow` with the double values, which will further lose precision. There's no point in converting an already-lossy value to a high-precision value... it can't magically recover the data.

Just pass a *string* to the `BigDecimal` constructor for the first argument, and [`BigDecimal.pow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#pow%28int%29) to do the computation.

Sample code:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal inputOne = new BigDecimal("95.123");
        int power = 12;
        BigDecimal result = inputOne.pow(power);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
548815620517731830194541.899025343415715973535967221869852721
```

(It looks like your expected value is actually truncated... the exact value should definitely end in a 1, as 3<sup>12</sup> ends in a 1.)

Comment: He truncated number on `218698`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use BigDecimal before you do the pow. For example, the following returns the expected result:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("95.123").pow(12));
```

Note, the value passed into `BigDecimal` must be a `String` because a `double` doesn't have enough precision to hold the exact value.

Answer (score 1):

Use `BigDecimal#pow` not `Math.pow`.